# Why is modulo resulting in floating point numbers?

Tags: python

I wrote some code that takes a 10 base number and converts it to a different base number.  The first iteration of the while loop produces an integer.  All subsequent iterations produce floating point numbers.  Why?  It is producing the correct answer, but as floating point.  Any idea why?

```
num = 128
abase = 2
tlist = []
while num > 0:
    tcr = num%abase
    tlist.append(tcr)
    num -= tcr
    num = num / abase
print(tlist)
tlist = tlist[::-1]

temp = 0
for item in tlist:
    temp *= 10
    temp += item         

temp = str(temp)
print(temp)
```

Comment: I would assume it has something to do with `num / abase`.

Comment: You should be using [divmod](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> x // y    (floored) quotient of x and y

It is because of the `num = num / abase` division operator. Change it to: `num = num // abase`

Updated code:

```
def test():
    num = 128
    abase = 2
    tlist = []
    while num > 0:
        tcr = num%abase
        tlist.append(tcr)
        num -= tcr
        num = num // abase
    print(tlist)
    tlist = tlist[::-1]

    temp = 0
    for item in tlist:
        temp *= 10
        temp += item         

    temp = str(temp)
    print(temp)

test()
```

Output:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
10000000
```

Reference:

- https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-long-complex

Comment: Thanks!  I'll check out the reference.